# How do I read all registers of an INA219 sensor via SMBus in Python at once?

Tags: pi-3b+, i2c, python-3, raspbian-buster, raspbian-lite

I'm trying to Connect my Raspberry Pi 3B+ with a Raspbian 10 to an INA219 current sensor (that also returns voltage and a premultiplied power) via SMBus in Python 3.7. After destroying one Raspberry 2B I ended up with a Raspbian 10, installed on a Raspberry 2B and now running the same image on a Raspberry 3B+. This worked perfectly, but I will try a clean OS installation, if the problem is suspected to come from the OS installation.

Please note, I'm aware of Adafruit libraries, but I can't use them in my case, as they don't read registers all at once and they are not compatible to a framework I'm using, but SMBus is.

I can read each register and perform setup/calibration according to some easy-to-find examples and with the help of the data sheet, but I can't get `smbus.read_i2c_block_data(addr, cmd, data)` to work.

After searching for similar problems I basically came across the issue of a repeated start-condition as opposed to a stop-condition. I know that SMBus is just a subset of I²C and that this may apply, here, but the datasheet states that SMBus is supported. It even uses a repeated start-condition in the high-speed I²C handshake. Also `echo -n 1 > /sys/module/i2c_bcm2708/parameters/combined` didn't help (and it was gone after a reboot, so I would have to add another startup dependency, anyway).

When I read each register with `smbus.read_word_data(addr, cmd, data)` (after initializing config and calibration with 2 calls to `smbus.write_word_data(addr, cmd, data)` at the right point in time) I get this, for example:

```
[0, 66, 40, 216, 0, 7, 0, 24]
```

This is completely fine and it translates to 0.6 mV shunt voltage, 5.2 V bus voltage, 38 mW power and 6.6 mA current, which is correct. But when I try to read the registers `0x01` to `0x04` at once (words split into big endian bytes, and yes, starting at `0x01` is correct), I get:

```
[0, 0, 0, 66, 0, 255, 0, 255]
```

The first line always changes according to measured values and the first 2 bytes of both sequences are roughly equal (here, it is equal, but it sometimes differed a bit). So the first register seems to be read. The rest of the second sequence only contains `0xFF` bytes, no matter how many registers I want to read.

Normally, if I make mistakes, I mostly get I/O errors or read values are rather `0x00` than `0xFF`, but this behavior opens some questions to me:

1. How can I solve this with a block read via SMBus?
2. Has anyone done this successfully?
3. What am I doing wrong, here?

---

Edit: `smbus.read_word_data(addr, cmd, data)` is called with these arguments:

- `addr=0x40` (also `0x41`, `0x44`, `0x45` for one of my 4 sensors respectively)
- `cmd=0x01`: starts with the second register
- `data=0x04`: reads 4 consecutive 16 bit registers
- returns a list of 4 short integers (16 bit each)

I also tried to set `data=0x08`, as I wasn't sure, if I didn't miss something and the function would actually read bytewise instead of per register. I noticed that I made a mistake with the interpretation, so I updated the suspicios result above, too.

With the BME280 sensor, I use `read_word_data` just as I do it here. That works fine.

Comment: Just a quick reply.  I spent over 20+ hours to learn to use Rpi3B+ stretch IDLE python 3.7.3 SMBus block read and failed (will give you the link of details later).  Then I googled to find that the SMBus block read is not completely supported.  What is worst is the following: (1) You cannot do "bus/cycle" stretching, (2) You cannot lower I2C speed, say to 10kHz, as a get around faking cycle stretching.  Now the good news, Rpi4B buster can lower I2C speed to fake cycle stretching, and solve/get around related SMBus block read problems.

Comment: The following forum posts are related to my testing I2C block read commands: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&hilit=i2c+block+read&start=350#p1355771.

Comment: You are making us guess at the call which is failing.  That wastes our time and your time. `read_i2c_block_data(addr, cmd, data)` takes three parameters.  I have no idea what you have set them too.  Please edit your question to include the command issued and the response.

Comment: Clock stretching is a huge kludge regardless, at least IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The INA219, like many other I2C devices, does not have some kind of "auto increment" for the register pointer. (The datasheet says that implicitly: "the INA219 retains the register pointer value **until it is changed by the next write operation**.")

What this means is that you can only read *one* 16 bit register per I2C transaction; any data read beyond those 16 bits in the same transaction is basically undefined.

If you want to read the same register again, you have to start a new read transaction.

If you want to read *any* other register, you have to explicitly write the new register pointer value and then perform a new read.